# How to define a function in scm scheme that tests if its parameter is a macro?

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme, bigloo

For example, assuming 'match is a macro and 'car isn't:

```
> (macro? 'match)
#t
> (macro? 'car)
#f
```

Answer (score 1):

Most schemes have no such `macro?` function. To distinguish normal functions from macros you can use `procedure?` from RnRS:

```
> (procedure? car)
#t
```

Comment: Does this really work for macros? Isn't `(procedure? let)` a syntax error?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Yes, you might need to catch an error. In bigloo, your example reports `Unbound variable -- let`.

Comment: Thank you both for your help with this. Perhaps this is a good time to provide you with my rationale for asking that question: a couple of months ago, while I was trying  to port Andrew Wright's Softscheme system to a modern Scheme (Bigloo, ChezScheme, or Racket), I came across that 'macro?' function call in his source code (written in ChezScheme from the early 90's). Apparently, that function was in those early (proprietary) versions of chezscheme.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot name the keyword using Scheme syntax:

```
> (procedure? let)
Exception: invalid syntax let
```

So you have to use a symbol, like `'let`, to refer to it. Given that `eval` needs to be able to tell keywords apart from other identifiers, you can try something like this:

```
(define keyword?
    (lambda (symbol)
      (guard (x [else (syntax-violation? x)])
        (eval symbol)
        #f)))
(keyword? 'let) ⇒ #t

(keyword? 'car) ⇒ #f

(keyword? 'does-not-exist) ⇒ #f
```

But this is certainly a rather big hammer. And this single-argument form of `eval` is a Chez Scheme extension, supplying `(interaction-environment)` as the default environment. It is also not completely safe because this hangs:

```
(let-syntax ([foo (lambda (x) (raise "oops"))])
    (keyword? 'foo))
```